# Getting OLB Card links or buttons inside the Iframe to be able to open a URL on Desktop and Mobile devices full screen

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

What method is suggested for opening a URL from a plugin card?
While NOT utilizing or having the additional Card Action button.
As understandably the card iframe is sandboxed, is there any call via window.postMessage that would allow for opening a URL or any other suggestions ?
Some methods work on desktop; but not on mobile. Would especially prefer opening in user's true web browser outside of the OLB mobile app since if we do go to a new URL there would be no navigation options to go back to the OLB dashboard.

SOME of the possible approaches tried so far include...

```
top.location.href = "https://linkplaceholder";
top.window.open("https://linkplaceholder");
window.top.location = "https://linkplaceholder";  // WORKS ON DESKTOP ONLY
window.parent.location.href = "https://linkplaceholder";
window.open("https://linkplaceholder");
window.open("https://linkplaceholder", '_blank');
window.open("https://linkplaceholder", '_system');
```

[Card Screenshot A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxLye.png)
[Card Screenshot B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSdCY.png)

Comment: FYI, I am aware of the restrictions link  https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/restrictions/  and wondered if needing to use the call-to-action button, How to dynamically change some arguments to allow the secondary application to know what the intended goal should be?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to take a look at our [Designing and Developing Plugins](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/guides/designinganddevelopingplugins/#activating-the-expanded-view-from-the-card-face) guide, specifically the *"Activating the Expanded View from the Card Face"* section.

The `Plugin Bridge` JavaScript module is the best way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much; but when trying to install the bridge, keep hitting road blocks like... https://artifactory.banno-tools.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm/acorn-walk/-/acorn-walk-8.1.1.tgz    ERROR 401 UNAUTHORIZED

Comment: We haven't had any other reports of errors using the **npm** route to install the dependency and are unable to reproduce the problem ourselves. We're hoping that the problem was only momentary. Perhaps trying again might work (and maybe on a _different_ machine)?